# multipar HTTP POST - objective-c

Tags: objective-c, http, post

I try to send a POST to my php page for upload a file and put it in a specific folder, this is the code I use on my osx app:

```
- (NSMutableURLRequest *) createRequest:(NSString *)string {

NSData *xmlData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:string];

NSString *urlString = @"http://www.allmyapp.net/wp-content/uploadFile.php";

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name='userfile'; filename='%@';\r\n",[string lastPathComponent]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:xmlData]];
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name='dest'\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Test Path" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];

return request;
```

}

and this is my php:

```
$uploaddir = 'test/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

echo('Dest:' . $_POST['dest'] . '     ');

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
    echo "Possibile attacco tramite file upload!\n";
}

echo 'Alcune informazioni di debug:';
print_r($_FILES);
```

The file is uploaded while I don't see **$_POST['dest']** where is the mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not setting the content type for `Dest` content part. This:

```
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name='dest'\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Test Path" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

should be:

```
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name='dest'\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Test Path" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```